# Rails - how to render my own action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, action, render

I am building simple shopping cart.
This is the route, where is are the data:

> match 'kosik/osobni-udaje' => 'home#cart_personal_data', :as =>
>   :cart_personal_data

And in this partial is form for **orders** (`= form_for @order do |f|`) - this form goes to:

```
  def update
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    fname = Order.check_attribute(params[:order][:first_name], 3, 40)
    lname = Order.check_attribute(params[:order][:last_name], 3, 40)

    if fname.nil? || lname.nil?
      @err = ''
      @err += 'Name is required<br />'
      @err += 'Surname is required<br />'
      render action: "/kosik/osobni-udaje"

    else
      respond_to do |format|
        if @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
          format.html { redirect_to cart_summary_path }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        else
          format.html { render action: "/kosik/osobni-udaje" }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

If the app goes to the first **if** block (where is the variable `@err`), then is the app rendered to the URL **/orders/9**.
But I would need to go to the previous URL - to the **kosik/osobni-udaje**.

Also, I have tried to check the log, but there is only following error message:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template orders/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I solved it this way:

```
if fname.nil? || lname.nil?
  @err = ''
  @err += '...'
  @err += '...'

  flash[:error] = @err
  redirect_to :back
...
```

and in the view just

```
- if flash[:error]
  %p #{flash[:error]}
```

This is probably not the best possible solution, but it's definitely working...

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this :

```
  def update
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    fname = Order.check_attribute(params[:order][:first_name], 3, 40)
    lname = Order.check_attribute(params[:order][:last_name], 3, 40)

    if fname.nil? || lname.nil?
      @err = ''
      @err += 'Name is required<br />'
      @err += 'Surname is required<br />'
      render action: "/kosik/osobni-udaje"

    else
      if @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to cart_summary_path }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      else
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { render action: "/kosik/osobni-udaje" }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
```

Just change the position of "respond_to"
      end

Comment: the program goes only to the IF block (because `fname` is NIL => which is correct), but the line `render action: "/kosik/osobni-udaje"` doesn't render the action `"/kosik/osobni-udaje"`, but `/orders/9` - if I remove the line `"/kosik/osobni-udaje"`, even then is app redirected to `/orders/9`

Comment: if I use `redirect_to "/kosik/osobni-udaje"` - good, I am redirected to the set URL (the problem - doesn't exist the `@err` variable). If I use `render action: "/kosik/osobni-udaje"`, I am redirected to `/order/9`... but why is not rendered `"/kosik/osobni-udaje"` page???

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
render 'home/cart_personal_data'
```

The URI `"/kosik/osobni-udaje"` isn't really an action, even though there is a route pointing to it. `render` wants something in terms of controllers and actions, or files. See the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for details.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you code is wrong.

You should place you validation in a custom validator like the example in the guide here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations. After, you could do that :

```
def update
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  if @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cart_summary_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
     end
   else
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { render action: "/kosik/osobni-udaje" }
       format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
end
```